# control chart in d3?

Tags: charts, d3.js, controls, visualization

Looking for a good **control chart**  (something like this http://www.pavementinteractive.org/wp-content/uploads/2007/08/Control_chart_individual.gif) **preferably in d3**?

Ive checked [d3 gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery) but no luck.

Comment: What do you mean by 'control'? The chart in your link is bread and butter D3 but it would help if you went into a bit more detail about what specifically you need to do. i.e. can you already draw lines in D3 but need help with another element of that 'control chart'? A really great resource to get you started with D3 is https://leanpub.com/D3-Tips-and-Tricks/read

Comment: @ninjaPixel: think OP means [Control Charts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_chart) as used in Statistical Process Control.

Comment: Nothing like this AFAIK, but should be straightforward to do.

Comment: yep its like what @sfinnie said, a line graph with lcl(lower control limit) and ucl(upper control limit)

Comment: Too bad no premade (d3) examples :( more wok when you have to build it all from scratch from a bare template

Comment: I found this online, using highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/Se6hL/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added Upper Limit and Lower Limit lines to regular line chart template.

http://vida.io/documents/GtQneTiCfoijXRuCQ

You can modify the values in the code.